# What are the worksheet RowXColumn limitations for the Excel Web App?

Tags: excel, web-applications

For example the client program lists the worksheet limitations here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx

But I can't find anything on the limitations of the web app.

Comment: 16384 cols x 1048576 rows

Comment: Do you have a reference for those values?

Comment: No - I went to the web app and scrolled down and right. Seems like they'd want to synch up with the dimensions of the desktop product though...

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Tim Williams response I think the row and column limitations for the Excel web app are 16384 cols x 1048576 rows.